# Level "n" comments data model

Tags: mongodb, nosql, elk

Best approach to build `scalable` Level "n" comments `NO-SQL` data model and ELK index mapping with analyser.

Can we implement with `NoSQL` database.

I am still not sure Nested vs Parent-Child performance in ELK to implement n-level comment module